# React Native Expo with symlink

Tags: react-native, expo, symlink

I want to create a React Native application with Expo, but I'm having problems displaying the project on my phone (Android).
Based on the documentation, I ran the command:

> npx create-expo-app --template

Then I chose the *Blank template* and gave my application a name.
Since I'm using a symlink (my folder is on my D: drive), I had to add a *metro.config.js* file to avoid a ReferenceError. It looks like this:

> module.exports = {    resolver: {         extraNodeModules: {},   },
> watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../")], };

Then I restarted my server with

> npx expo (*or* npm run start)

Strangely, after that, bundling became extremely slow. After waiting several minutes, I scan the QR code with the Expo Go application and all I get is a blank screen with the expo icon. So I refresh the page and get the following error:

> "Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to
> *[same port as my application]* from / *[a different port]* after 10000ms"

I should point out that I get the same thing when I enter the URL manually.
Obviously, my phone is connected to the same Wi-Fi as my computer.